# Rounded corners for each entry in listview android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to make every entry that will have a rounded corners like this[image: 1]

This is what I get,

[image: 2]

With this code

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" />
```

Is there a way to make like this?

[image: 3]

This what I have done so far for my list_rows.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:padding="15dip" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need give rounded corners to list item and not list view, Please provide code for list item as well

Comment: Set `android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"` in the layout of list item and not list view

Comment: I already added my list_rows.xml, is it enough? I haven't tried it since I dont have a backend yet.

Answer (score 0):

Added padding on listview and remove background from listview

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="650dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_item"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp" />
```

And added background in item view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```